# Rails + HTTPS: Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, https

I think my sessions and such are screwing up because of the code I recently added in to ensure proper protocol (https on some pages, and http on others). I'm not sure though. But I keep seeing `Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected` in my log.

the `:ensure_proper_protocol method is referring to a method I have in my application controller:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      CONTROLLERS_THAT_REQUIRE_SSL = ['check_out', 'users', 'sessions', 'registrations', 'addresses', 'catalog_requests', 'wine_club/orders']

      def ensure_proper_protocol
        unless Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
          if request.format == "text/html" && request.protocol["https"] && !CONTROLLERS_THAT_REQUIRE_SSL.include?(params[:controller])
            redirect_to "http://" + request.host + request.path
          end
        end
      end
```

And for the controllers in CONTROLLERS_THAT_REQUIRE_SSL, I add `force_ssl` like so:

```
class CheckOutController < ApplicationController

   force_ssl
   ...
```

However, I'm wondering if the switch in protocols is screwing my sessions up. Are my session issues and this error related? How do I fix the "filter chain halted" error?

The session issues I'm having is with Devise and authentication. I have a before filter to :authenticate_user! and although I manage to log in, it doesn't seem to stay logged in. The problem is that there are no error messages. It just logs out for some reason, and I'm pretty sure that it's because of the redirect because I have a before filter in my application controller to see if the user is signed in, and it uses the devise helper method `user_signed_in?` to see if the user is signed in. Take a look at my log:

```
    Cache read: https://mysite-rc-preview.mysite.com/users/sign_in?
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 69.193.194.58 at 2013-09-04 12:09:38 -0400
    Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bSYhk5t7VPBUTGkQuVyix8cb7Et7yojPE5m0V/g+do8=", "user"=>{"email"=>"emai@mysite.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
    inside setup_cart. current_cart_id is 55005260
    55005260
    request.session_options[:id] = eecb979b4d7db5bfd28a3684ef7288d3
      User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'emai@mysite.com' LIMIT 1
       (1.9ms)  BEGIN
       (2.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2013-09-04 16:07:44.987529', "current_sign_in_at" = '2013-09-04 16:09:39.171144', "sign_in_count" = 34, "updated_at" = '2013-09-04 16:09:39.174358' WHERE "users"."id" = 350492
       (10.6ms)  COMMIT
    begining get_or_create_cart session[:current_cart_id] is 55005260
      Cart Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."user_id" = 350492 AND "carts"."id" = 55005260 LIMIT 1
      Cart Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."user_id" = 350492
    end of get_or_create_cart session[:current_cart_id] is 54993421
      SeoContent Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "seo_contents".* FROM "seo_contents" WHERE "seo_contents"."for_section" = 'default' LIMIT 1
    There's no session[:cvv] variable
      Cart Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."web_cart_session" = 'eecb979b4d7db5bfd28a3684ef7288d3'
      Cart Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."user_id" = 350492 AND "carts"."name" = 'My Cart' LIMIT 1
      CartItem Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "cart_items".* FROM "cart_items" WHERE "cart_items"."cart_id" = 55005260 ORDER BY created_at
       (1.9ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (2.4ms)  DELETE FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1  [["id", 55005260]]
       (6.5ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to https://mysite-rc-preview.mysite.com/
    Completed 302 Found in 408ms (ActiveRecord: 42.0ms)
    Cache read: https://mysite-rc-preview.mysite.com/?
    Started GET "/" for 69.193.194.58 at 2013-09-04 12:09:39 -0400
    Processing by SiteController#index as HTML
    Redirected to http://mysite-rc-preview.mysite.com/
    Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected
    Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    Cache read: http://mysite-rc-preview.mysite.com/?
    Started GET "/" for 69.193.194.58 at 2013-09-04 12:09:39 -0400
    Processing by SiteController#index as HTML
    inside setup_cart. current_cart_id is 54993421
    54993421
    request.session_options[:id] = 4bec2bbc42e8213be89aaf6431b41535
    inside not user_signed_in? clause of setup_cart
```

It redirects me to the homepage after log in, which is okay, but after that it redirects from http:// ... / to https:// ... / , which causes the user to not be signed in anymore. Could this be because my sessions aren't being stored in the database as I configured them to be? I do have this line in my config/initializers/session_store.rb:

`mysite::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store`

Comment: It would be helpful to know what sort of session issues you were encountering, including error messages.

Comment: Ok give me a sec I'll update the post

Comment: @Veraticus I updated it

Comment: have you found any solutions for this issue?