# Rails + Sessions: How do I test that my sessions are being stored in the active record store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Right now I'm having an issue with my sessions (or so I believe). My original problem can be found here: [Rails + HTTPS: Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618318/rails-https-filter-chain-halted-as-ensure-proper-protocol-rendered-or-redire) . I think the redirect from HTTPS to HTTP and vice versa is somehow losing my session.

However, I do have this line in my config/initializers/session_store.rb:

`mysite::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store`

so it's weird that anything gets lost in the process of redirecting. How would I check that the `session` variables that I store are actually being stored in the database and not on the server? Are there any commands I could run in the console?

Comment: You could look in the database. How are you serving?

Comment: What do you mean by serving?

Comment: What is serving your application's pages?

Comment: ubuntu + apache + passenger

Comment: Some servers don't share sessions between HTTP and HTTPS unless they're configured to do so, although I don't recall any specifics.